# ALSA soc_pcm_open() is not invoked

Tags: linux, alsa

I am integrating a Audio AD/DA to an embedded Linux (v3.10.49) platform.
However, I can't find the reason that ALSA soc_pcm_open() is not invoked.
Is there any command in user space required to invoke soc_pcm_open() in kernel space ? 
Or, how should I carry on ?

Comment: There is a bug in your driver. Which you have not shown.

Comment: Thanks CL, which files/functions/structures do you refer to ?

Comment: Potentially, all of them.

Answer (score 1):

aplay,amixer are user space commands to invoke ALSA Lib functions like soc_pcm_open()

Take care below items

- Make sure sound card is available and has proper hardwares,
  /proc/asound directory has information.
- Use proper amixer commands before aplay if needed.
- With aplay, use proper hardware i.e hw:0,0,    hw:0,1 .. etc.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, a amix followed by a aplay commdand trigger a flow to soc_pcm_open().